# Why I keep getting the `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BufferedWriter` error?

Tags: python, pdf, fastapi, bytesio

There is something very basic that I'm not able to do. In this code :

```py
@app.get('/resume')
async def resume():
    path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    with open(f'{path}/cv.pdf', 'rb') as f:
        data_binary = f.read()
        file_data = base64.b64encode(data_binary)

    with open(f'{path}/sample.pdf','wb') as pdf:
        pdf.write(file_data)
        parsed_data = ResumeParser(pdf).get_extracted_data()
    pdf.close()
    return await process_pdf(parsed_data)
```

I'm getting the error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BufferedWriter` over and over again for the line `ResumeParser(pdf).get_extracted_data()` when :

```py
parsed_data = ResumeParser(f'{path}/cv.pdf').get_extracted_data()
```

is working perfectly.

Do you know by any chance what I'm missing here please ?

TYVM.

For the context :

1. Obviously, I tried to convert the base64 file to bytes with `BytesIO`
2. `ResumeParser` is coming from this package `pyresparser`
3. I don't know if this is related but I never see this `sample.pdf` file created in my file system.
4. I'm trying to convert a pdf file to base64 in order to make it work also with a frontend app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResumeParser appears to want the path to the file to parse.  You are supplying the contents of the file in the **pdf** variable.   you don't need the with clause there.  also your with clause would automatically close the pdf file when the with is exited.  You do not need the explicit close() call.  I have updated that section and included it here.

```
 with open(f'{path}/sample.pdf','wb') as pdf:
        pdf.write(file_data)

 parsed_data = ResumeParser(f'{path}/sample.pdf').get_extracted_data()
```

The above code writes and closes the file and then passes the name to resume parser.  I think that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ty LhasaDad, so do you mean something like :
`pdf = open(f'{path}/sample.pdf','wb') pdf.write(file_data) pdf.close() parsed_data = ResumeParser(pdf).get_extracted_data()` ? Because it still returns the error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BufferedWriter`

Comment: updated my answer to give a bit more guidance and example of what I am saying to do.

Comment: Ok, I start to understand what was my mistake. But still, when I'm printing `parsed_data`, I'm getting `{'name': None, 'email': None, 'mobile_number': None, 'skills': [], 'college_name': None, 'degree': None, 'designation': None, 'experience': None, 'company_names': None, 'no_of_pages': None, 'total_experience': 0}` and I'm scared it is because `f'{path}/sample.pdf'` is empty.

Comment: And I have no `sample.pdf` in my file system after running my script. I also tried to create an empty `sample.pdf` file before but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: And I added this little `+` sign in the open method as well.

Comment: I think I don't have any `sample.pdf` in my file system because I'm using Docker for this app.

Comment: @Sourouche You could either copy it in to the docker image when building with dockerfile or you could mount a directory and reference that directery with a sample file in it so the container sees it from your host file system.

Comment: also, the way your code was written it looks like you are trying to CREATE sample.pdf with the open for write that you were doing with the with() statement.  it should exist.  I think a bigger issue for you is that the base64 encode is probably the wrong thing, above.  you may want to be doing a decode instead?    not sure how your ResumeParser works, but guessing it does not want something that has been base64 encoded.

Comment: maybe try printing what you were going to write into it before you open it for write?  it could be that you are writing nothing into it. print(file_data)

Comment: you were perfectly right, I'm going to write the final solution in a new comment and validate your answer as the good one. There is no words to thank you enough so just, tyvm buddy.

Answer (score 0):

So, the final code to make this work is :

```
@app.get('/resume')
async def resume():
    path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    with open(f'{path}/cv.pdf', 'rb') as f:
        data_binary = f.read()
        # file_data = base64.b64encode(data_binary) <= as @LhasaDad pointed it out, ResumeParser is not waiting for a base64 encode

    with open(f'{path}/sample.pdf','wb') as pdf:
        pdf.write(data_binary)
    parsed_data = ResumeParser(f'{path}/sample.pdf').get_extracted_data() <= it returns the right answer.
```